# App crashes on start because of this one line

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Let me get this straight.
I know where my issue is.
I just don't know why it's happening...

When I take out this line:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null)
                        sendFCMTokenToDatabase(task.getResult().getToken());
                });
```

It works.

Also the log cat says this when the app crashes.

**E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{663eb36 u0 Application Error: com.eamon.jaber} has no registered input channel**

If you need anything else please comment thanks :)

Please help thanks!

Comment: Could you please include the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I am trying to find the stack trace of the crash idk where it is

Comment: To get the stack trace: run your app, open the logcat bottom bar, copy the error log, and update your question